# Python variables not accesible in pyconsole (PythonTeX)

Tags: python

This MWE is self explanatory:

```
% Compile this with pdflatex -> pythontex.py -> pdflatex
\documentclass[a6paper]{article}

\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\pyb{pi=3.14159}

$\pi$ is \py{pi}

\begin{pyconsole}
pi
\end{pyconsole}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\py` and `\pyb` commands are executed via a Python script.  The `pyconsole` environment is executed in a console emulation.  So there isn't overlap between the two, and variables aren't shared.  (Regular Python commands/environments always start with `py`, while everything console-related starts with `pycon`.)

You probably want to look into the `\pycon` and `\pyconc` commands.  The first is used for getting the value of a variable, while the second allows you to run console code without showing anything.  There is currently not a `\pyconb`. My reasoning is that showing code without output isn't console-like.  But I might consider adding such a command in the future.